# Force lost focus

Tags: android

Consider an activity with a few buttons.

We can dynamically assign the focus this way:

```
b1.requestFocus();
```

If the user double taps the button, I want force a *loss* of focus.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to detect a double tap. One way is to start a timer on the first tap, and check whether the same button is tapped again within the timeout value.

You can lose focus by setting `setFocusable` to false.

Comment: With this excellent timer trick, try `b1.clearFocus()` if you want the user to be able to click the button again.